# Resort reservation: Booked for 5, 6 are staying

Tags: regulations, bookings, beaches, sleeping

I'm booking a week long trip at a beach resort in the US and the largest room says it sleeps 5 people. There will be 6 of us. But one person will just bring an air mattress because it is a VERY spacious suite having 2 separate rooms. I am wondering, will the staff at the hotel confront us once they notice that 6 people are coming in and out often? or will they not even care?

Comment: It'll depend on the hotel. Some do, some don't.

Comment: Have you tried asking them? If the fire code allows it, many hotels will provide a roll-away or similar bed for an additional adult on payment of a suitable suppliment

Answer (score 2):

Unless you mean something different by 'resort', you are usually paying for more than just sleeping accommodation - food, use of beach, sports etc. Generally in such places you get a wristband that entitles you to access facilities and they will definitely notice and refuse to give out six wristbands.

If there are no facilities other than the room they may or may not notice but will probably still object if they do.

Comment: "Resort" applies to many more types of lodges other than the all inclusive.

Comment: @Tom You don't have to be "all inclusive" for there to be services other than the room that you are paying for.

Comment: I am simply saying that there are many 'resorts' that are just places to stay without including food or services.  And probably 90% of the 'resorts' we use on our cycle tours fall into that category.